# pi-hole: DataTables warning: table id=groupsTable - Invalid JSON response. ... see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Tags: networking, apache-httpd

Hello fellow tinkerers,

Struggled some time to get pihole working. In the browser, got constant JSON messages:

> DataTables warning: table id=groupsTable - Invalid JSON response. For
> more information about this error, please see
> http://datatables.net/tn/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, it turned out to be an easy fix.

```
apt install php-sqlite3 
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif 
a2enconf php7.3-fpm 
systemctl restart apache2
```

I am running Buster on PHP 7.3. on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.

Since I am running Apache in stead of default lightpd I also needed to add www-data to the pihole group, else you get the 'SQLite readonly database' error

```
more /etc/group | grep hole 
pihole:x:995:www-data
    
more /etc/gshadow | grep hole 
pihole:!::www-data
```

Hope this helps others too.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.